# What library to use to create a simple port scanner?

Tags: c++, c++builder, tcp

I need advise to create a simple port-scanner, who will need to detect if some specific devices are connected to the network from their IP/MAC address.

I am working on windows 7 and can use preferably C++ Builder 2010, or java or Qt.

The library have to be under a public domain or equivalent, as my software is a proprietary software.

What library would you advice? Do you know any free software that I could start from, or any examples?

What about using Indy Sockets or Synapse TCP/IP Libraries?

Comment: http://zeromq.org/ my 2 cent

Comment: Hi thanks, but I can not distribute the resulting work (as zeromq.org's license required)

Comment: you can do whatever you want with 0mq http://zeromq.org/area:licensing , the license is an LGPL, same as the free version of QT for example.

Comment: Oh yes sorry i missed read it, you are right, I will have a look then. Thanks

Comment: It seems that all libraries available are made for Visual Studio compiler, whereas I am using C++ Builder 2010 Embarcadero, I already tried to convert a similar library called (SFML) from Visual C++ to Builder and I failed! I am looking at a C++ Builder friendly library. Thanks

Comment: suggestion: try their own forum or go on github.com or similar and use the search form.

Comment: @durje zeromq exposes a C api for its interface so creating an import library out of that for Embarcadero's compiler should pose no problem. I would know because I've done it before in the past.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any TCP/IP library will work.  Indy, ICS, Synapse, they all will work just fine with C++Builder.  Since Indy ships with C++Builder, you could start with that, but you are certainly not limited to it.

They all use WinSock internally on Windows, so you could just program to the WinSock API directly and not use any libraries at all.  All you would need to do is call `WSAStartup()` once at program startup, then call `socket()` and `connect()` for each port you want to check.  To check multiple ports, you can either put the sockets into non-blocking mode with `ioctlsocket()` and then use either `select()`, `WSAAsyncSelect()`, `WSAAsyncEvent()`, or `CreateIoCompletionPort()`/`GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` to detect whether `connect()` succeeds/fails, or you can put the sockets into blocking mode (their default mode) and use worker threads to call `connect()` and let it tell you directly if it succeeds/fails.

Answer (score 2):

An open port is a port which has a listening application on it. Simplest way to check a TCP port is trying to connect it and if the connection established then that port is open.

Advanced methods are based on fingerprinting and prob packets, you can read how [nmap](http://nmap.org/) detects open ports.

Finally, [pcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html) is a useful library for advanced network programming.

Comment: Hi M M. Thanks for your reply, do you know any example or function based on C++ Builder to try to open a connection and see if it establish or not. You are right I am looking for a solution as simple as that!

Answer (score 0):

For Borland C++ builder? Sorry, not much out there for Borland C++ builder,
 but if you could use Visual C++ Express and the WINSOCK library then it is as simple as this :

Winsock portscanner :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"WSOCK32.LIB")

void main()
{
   WSADATA data;
   SOCKET sock;
   int err,i,startport,endport;
   char ip[20];
   struct sockaddr_in sock_addr;
   FILE*fp1;

   printf("ip: ");
   scanf("\n%s",ip);
   printf("start port: ");
   scanf("%d",&startport);
   printf("end port: ");
   scanf("%d",&endport);
   if((WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0),&data)!=0))
   {
      printf("Error: Winsock did not init!!!\n\n");
   }
   else
   {
      for(i=startport;i<endport;i++)
      {
         sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
         sock_addr.sin_family=PF_INET;
         sock_addr.sin_port=htons(i);
         sock_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(ip);
         printf("Checking port %d\n",i);
         err=connect(sock,(struct sockaddr*)&sock_addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr));
         if(err==0)
         {
            printf("Port Open!!!\n\n\a");
            fp1=fopen("ports.txt","a+");
            fprintf(fp1,"Port is open: %d\n\n",i);
            closesocket(sock);
            fclose(fp1);
         }
         else
         {
            printf("Port Closed!!!\n\n");
         }
      }
      WSACleanup();
      system("ports.txt");
   }
}
```

Comment: This WINSOCK example should work with C++Builder, but I have not tested.  C++Builder also comes with the Indy library that covers all you TCP/UDP needs.

Comment: How would winsock be limited to Visual C++? Would work just fine for Borland/Embarcadero or several other compilers to.